# Removing all the Alphabets from a string using a single SQL Query

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a string '**ALbhabet123AndThenAlphabetAnd456789AndAlphabet**'. Need to replace all the strings and the output should be '**123456789**'. We can achieve this by using WHILE loop. But we need this in one single query. We then need to update the values in table. Is there a way to get the result set in a single query?
I am using `SQL 2008 R2` and above versions. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Create a function and use it. Tripp's link is ideal. This is when scalar functions make the most sense to use

Comment: would you like a function or just a select statement ?

Comment: Thanks Tripp. The link is ideal. Helped a lot.